# Dual Boot: Lan not working in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, network-manager, lan

I have dual boot with Ubuntu 15.04 and Windows 8.1. I mostly use Ubuntu and wasn't able to use lan, I though my port had some problem. Today I opened Windows for some work, and just connected Lan for experimenting and its working.

I tried sudo service network-manager restart several times in ubuntu. It does recognizes that something has been connected (the wifi bars keeps moving), but doesn't connect.

Does anyone know, how to make it work? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Even I  do have the same problem. I am using Acer V5-571 with Atheros drivers. Recently I managed to get it done using r8168 driver and blacklisting r8169 driver. After doing so LAN wont be connected till login, but after login it will be detected. But after few updates it stopped working. It seems the problem is with drivers.